# Selecting an Azure DevOps Build Agent Pool based on Availability

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, agent

Is it possible to get a yaml-based pipeline to select a build agent based on it's availability?  I know it's possible to use parameters to select from a set of choices, but I would like to use a self-hosted pool if available, otherwise use the Microsoft-hosted ones to reduce costs.  I cannot guarantee my pool will be up 24/7 but while i'm working it would be great if it choose my self-hosted pool by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. There is a feature request on developer community - [Allow agent pools to contain Microsoft hosted and self-hosted agents](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-agent-pools-to-contain-microsoft-hosted-and/396893), but this is not implemented yet.

Comment: @RNDThoughts can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?